# Inserting a view element in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have a view I want to insert into the DOM. As I understand it, the setElement method creates a jQuery element (saved as $el) which is unattached to the DOM. I'm trying to insert that jQuery element into an existing DOM element, without success.

```
SimpleView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function(){
        this.setElement('#simpleview');
        this.render();
    },

    render: function(){
        this.$el.appendTo('#container');
    }
});

var myview = new SimpleView();
```

What am I missing?

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pz8FE/2/)

Comment: Your view has no content, are you sure it isn't working, and you are just not seeing anything displayed?

Comment: I'm working with the developer console to see changes to the html and nothing happens.

Comment: I would put some content in there, and then make a jsFiddle if you are still having issues.

Comment: Ok I added some content to the element, here's the jsFiddle: [jsfiddle.net/pz8FE](http://jsfiddle.net/pz8FE/)

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined -- you need to add it to the fiddle.

Comment: This should work then: [jsfiddle.net/pz8FE/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/pz8FE/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand how [`setElement`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement) works. When you call `setElement`, you're supposed to give it a DOM element that **already exists** and then `setElement` does three things:

1. Sets the view's `el` to the element.
2. Undelegates the events from the old `el` and binds the view's events to the new `el`.
3. Caches a jQuery wrapped version of `el` in `$el`.

You seem to be calling `setElement` to try to create a new element with `id="simpleview"`. You probably just want to include [`id: 'simpleview'`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) in the view definition since

> `this.el` is created from the view's `tagName`, `className`, `id` and `attributes` properties, if specified. If not, **el** is an empty `div`.

You should get what you're looking for if your view looks more like this:

```
SimpleView = Backbone.View.extend({
    id: 'simpleview',
    initialize: function(){
        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
        this.$el.appendTo('#container');
    }
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/7GPEy/

Answer (score 1):

[This should do what you're after:](http://jsfiddle.net/pz8FE/7/)

```
$(function(){

    var SimpleView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: $('#container'),

        initialize: function () {
            this.render();
        },

        render: function () {
            this.$el.html('<div>HELLO</div>');
        }

    });

    var myview = new SimpleView();

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I adapted your solution and replaced `this.$el.html(...)` by `$('<div/>', {id:'simpleview',text:'hello'}).appendTo(this.el);`. The problem is, the events will now be delegated to the container, and not the view... I'd rather not have another issue emerge from the fix.